# Java not catching Exception in a catch block

Tags: java, selenium, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to implement a method for automated tests with Selenium and Cucumber, which currently looks like this:

```
public By getFromAccountSelector() {
    try {
        return By.xpath("//ib-dropdown[@ng-model='model.from']");
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        return By.xpath("//ib-dropdown[@ng-model='data.account']");
    }
}
```

What it's supposed to do is to map the word "fromAccount" in Gherkin to HTML elements that are looked up by their respective XPath expressions. If the method doesn't find the element by one expression, it's supposed to not throw the `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` it would normally throw in such a case, an instead attempt the search with the next expression.

However, the `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` is thrown regardless of what I put in the catch block. It's as if it was simply ignored. The program never even gets to the second block. I tried to substitute `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` into the catch, but the behavior stayed the same.

What's causing this and how do I fix it?

Stack Trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ib-dropdown[@ng-model='model.from']"}
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 367 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'GHKY9H2', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f), userDataDir=C:\Users\marecek\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Selenium\}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=62.0.3202.62, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 32332850f941b37dcb9ce6eaae527ea5
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//ib-dropdown[@ng-model='model.from']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:410)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:509)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
    at cz.bsc.tbcselenium.steps.common.CommonSeleniumStepDefinitions.click_combo_and_select(CommonSeleniumStepDefinitions.java:206)
    at ?.When click combo "fromAccount" and select item 3(src/main/resources/features/Test.feature:14)
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate He does say that he switched to the more specific exception and got the same behavior, and the stack trace does show that it's the `model.from` line.

Comment: As I said, I tried putting the more specific 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException' in there as well, but the stacktrace  stayed the same. It's the try block that throws it, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: OK, then, is it possible that somehow you haven't properly compiled this file and you're still using an old version (which is why no changes do anything)?  Or that it's running some other similar code when this exception is thrown, and not this code?

Comment: @Sargon1 If you put `System.out.println("I am in the try");` at the beginning of your `try` block, and `System.out.println("I am in the catch");` in your catch block, does it print the first and not the second?  (This is mostly a check that this is actually happening, and that it is coming from this code.)

Comment: I'm more of a breakpoint fan, but this too pointed to the behavior already described; The first String was printed, the second wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are catching it in a wrong place. The real thing happens in the CommonSeleniumStepDefinitions.java:206

By.xpath() does nothing, driver uses it to access an element.

Comment: As far as I can discern, that line just calls it: final WebElement combo = SeleniumTestContext.getWebDriver().findElement(by);

Comment: Try to add try/catch over there. By.xpath() doesn't throw any exception unless the xpath parameter is null. It's just a way to say what kind of a way to say to the driver what this selector is. The real job is done by driver.findElement()

Comment: If you want to test this, try changing your `try` block to prove where it's coming from.  `By b = By.xpath("//ib-dropdown[@ng-model='model.from']");
System.out.println("We got the value"); 
return b;`  If this prints, the exception isn't coming from that `try` block.

Comment: (or just separate the lines and use breakpoints; that works too.)

Comment: Ok, I get it now. It is indeed happening on line 206 in that introspection mumbo-jumbo that one of our senior guys wrote that uses these selectors. I'll need to have a look at that, and go on from there. Thanks, guys.